# Write the associated dual problem for the following primal LP:

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex

Write the associated dual problem for the following primal LP:

$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Max  }~~~~ 2x_1+4x_2+4x_3-3x_4$$
$$\text{subject to } x_1+x_2+x_3 =4$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_1+4x_2+x_4 = 8$$
$$x_i \geq 0 ~~~\forall i$$

Following closely using the universally accepted primal - duality table, my answer is as follows:

$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Min  }~~~~ 4p_1+8p_2$$
$$\text{subject to } p_1+p_2 \leq 2$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~p_1+4p_2 \leq 4$$
$$~~~~~~~p_1 \leq 4$$
$$~~~~~~~~~p_2 \leq -3$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~p_1,p_2 \text{ free}$$

But i got very confused when my prof's solution is as follows:
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Min  }~~~~ 4p_1+8p_2$$
$$\text{subject to } p_1+p_2 \geq 2$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~p_1+4p_2 \geq 4$$
$$~~~~~~~p_1 \geq 4$$
$$~~~~~~~~~p_2 \geq -3$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~p_1,p_2 \text{ free}$$

There is no more further explanation. So where did i go wrong?

Comment: Use the Lagrangian to derive the dual instead of a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the primal problem is a maximization problem the constraints in the dual which correspond to variables $\geq 0$ become constraints of the form $ax \geq b$ just as in your profs solution. If the primal is a minimization problem then the constraints will have the form $ax \leq b$ in the dual. My guess is that you looked at a duality table in which the primal problem is a minimization problem but you are dealing with a maximization problem in your example.

Comment: Do you mean for a maximization primal LP problem, the duality table will be exactly the opposite of the minimization primal LP problem?

Comment: Yes. If your primal in the table is a minimization problem then just look at the dual problem in the table (,which will then be a maximization problem) and treat this as the primal for your transformation. This is possible because the dual of the dual will give you the primal.